# deleted content on /home/site/wwwroot when setting WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE on true

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a docker container with a php app inside (custom image)

The app is up and running without problems - with WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE==false.

If i change this setting to true then the content of /home/site/wwwroot is completly deleted

Any idea ?

WITHOUT mount or WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE everything is working....

any help/idea is welcome

regards

this is my application setting :

[image]

Comment: Can you try to create a linux container app directly, and then add this configuration. Before adding, you can freely put a text file under wwwroot to check whether it exists after configuration.

Comment: I followed the steps just mentioned 6 hours ago and tested it and everything is running normally.

Comment: can you please clarify these steps ?

Comment: 1. create a default linux container app on portal, don't need your custom docker file, just default.

2. open kudu site (/newui), and  upload a new file， just  make sure under wwwroot folder, there are two file in there, (hoststart.html and a test file).

3. add `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE==true` ,then check the content of wwwroot folder.

Comment: i need my custom docker image , btw , when i put WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE = true , it's dosen't work for me , and the content is totaly deleted ( i only find hostingstart.html )

Comment: Because your problem cannot be reproduced, I suggest you raise a support ticket, let MSFT help you.

Comment: When the problem is solved, you are welcome to update the answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233882/discussion-between-quentin-merlin-and-jason-pan).

Answer (score 1):

According to Azure Docs, when `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` is set to `true` your App Service directory gets mounted into `/home`. If you FTP into your app service, you'll see the default folder structure, LogFiles, site, Data folders, etc. If you were running an app directly on azure, your site files would be in `/site/wwwroot` but since you're mounting a docker image, that gets run instead.

But `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` allows you to access the persistent storage on your App Service plan to share some files across instances. So you can share config files, log files, etc. In the past I've used it to mount a share to allow me to run Lets Encrypt and validate via URL.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux